# Determine job_id from within the code-block for a cron job in Rufus Scheduler (rails 3.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rufus-scheduler

When creating a cron job through the Rufus Scheduler, is there some way 
within the code-block for the cron job to determine the job_id of the
cron job itself?

What I want to do is something like this:

```
scheduler.cron '0 0 0 * * * Etc/GMT+0' do
  # Nix existing jobs.
  scheduler.cron_jobs.values.map { |j| if j.job_id != self.job_id then j.unschedule end }     
  ...
end
```

The problem is `self.job_id`.  Any suggestions on how to retrieve the
current job_id of the cron that is currently being triggered?

I know there is something like "triggered_threads", which returned
currently running jobs.  But I want something more specific:  the
job_id of the code-block I am currently within.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by supplying the scheduler.cron method invocation with the an optional parameter that explicitly identified the new job's ID:

```
scheduler.cron '0 0 0 * * * Etc/GMT+0', {:job_id => explicit_job_id} do
  # Nix existing jobs.
  scheduler.cron_jobs.values.map { |j| if j.job_id != self.job_id then j.unschedule end }     
  ...
end
```

where `explicit_job_id` is some variable defined before the scheduler.cron invocation is made.